# post_type filter for post does not exclude pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following problem in Wordpress. I have this code in function.php which should make posts title on frontend from Yoast SEO title. Code works, however it has also impact on pages.

```
  function set_my_seo_title($title, $id)

{
    global $post;
    $seo_title=get_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);         
    return ((!empty($seo_title)&&$post->post_type=='post') ? $seo_title : $title);
}

add_filter('the_title', 'set_my_seo_title', 15, 2);
```

The problem is with condition `post_type=='post'`. It looks like there is some bug in Wordpress, but may be I am doing something wrong.

**Important:**  I have to admit I am not good developer. This code is from other question. If you know solution for this please post your full code variant. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [get_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) instead...

```
function set_my_seo_title( $title, $id ) {
    $seo_title = get_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true );
    return ( ( ! empty( $seo_title ) && get_post_type( $id ) == 'post' ) ? $seo_title : $title );
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'set_my_seo_title', 15, 2 );
```